# How to add properties to "videoconvert" element using Gst.Pipeline

Tags: python, gstreamer, pygobject, gobject

I am tring to write a gstreamer pipeline using **Gst.Pipeline()**. The problem is that I can't figure out how to convert "string" pipeline to gst.pipeline, how to add properties to the **videoconvert** element?

for example for a pipeline like this:
`**<some src...>** ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! **<some enc...>**`
I dont undewrstand how to set the propety **video/x-raw,format=I420** for the **videoconvert** ElementFactory

I tried this but its not working..

```
convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "convert")
caps_str = "video/x-raw,format=I420"
caps = Gst.Caps.from_string(caps_str)
convert.set_property("caps", caps)
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: object of type `GstVideoConvert' does not have property 'caps'
```

Comment: why not use `Gst.parseLaunch('... ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! ...')`?

Comment: Your issue is that you are trying to set caps on the videoconvert element whereas your pipeline string correctly shows that they are a caps filter following the videoconvert in the pipeline.

Comment: Currently I am doing what you offer with the Gst.parseLaunch and it's work. but I want it to work with the gst.pipeline.

Comment: then you'll need to add a caps filter to the pipeline and link the videoconvert to the new caps filter manually (see https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/capsfilter.html?gi-language=c#capsfilter-page)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the plugin `videoconvert` doesn't have the property "caps". The correct way is

```
convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "convert")
capsfilter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "capsfilter")
caps_str = "video/x-raw,format=I420"
caps = Gst.Caps.from_string(caps_str)
capsfilter.set_property("caps", caps)
```

The element `convert` will link to `capsfilter`.